# Get CodeMirror instance

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I want to get an instance of CodeMirror (it is binded to a textarea '#code'). From an onclick-event I want to add a value to the current value of the CodeMirror instance. How can this be achieved? From the docs I can't seem to find anything to get an instance and bind it to a loca var in javascript.

Comment: Can you post what you have so far?

Comment: The documentation shows `var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror(document.body);`... is that what you want?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Someone just posted an answer but removed it. Nevertheless, it was a working solution.
Thanks!

-- Basically this was his solution:

```
// create an instance
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea('code');
// store it
$('#code').data('CodeMirrorInstance', editor);
// get it
var myInstance = $('code').data('CodeMirrorInstance');
// from here on the API functions are available to 'myInstance' again.
```

Comment: that's clever, but what's about vice versa? Does CodeMirror holds info about element it linked to?

Comment: oh, just have found: cm.getTextArea().

Answer (score 76):

Another method I have found [elsewhere](http://wisercoder.com/get-reference-codemirror-instance/) is as follows:

```
//Get a reference to the CodeMirror editor
var editor = document.querySelector('.CodeMirror').CodeMirror;
```

This works well when you are creating the CodeMirror instance dynamically or replacing an existing DOM element with a CodeMirror instance.

Comment: And in order to use the original selector rather than just finding the first CodeMirror: `var originalDiv = $('#code'); originalDiv.next('.CodeMirror')[0].CodeMirror;`

Answer (score 10):

There is a `getWrapperElement` on code mirror editor objects which gives you the root DOM element of the code mirror instance:

```
var codemirrorDomElem = editor.getWrapperElement();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find the instance starting with the `<textarea>` and moving to the next sibling.

#### Native

- Functional

  ```
  document.querySelector('#code').nextSibling,
  ```
- Selector

  ```
  document.querySelector('#code + .CodeMirror'),
  ```

#### jQuery

- Functional

  ```
  $('#code').next('.CodeMirror').get(0),
  ```
- Selector

  ```
  $('#code + .CodeMirror').get(0)
  ```

> ***Extra:*** A more advanced solution involving [*clipboard.js*](http://zenorocha.github.io/clipboard.js/) -> [**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/3phdkg66/)

---

## Example

```js
// Selector for textarea
var selector = '#code';

$(function() {
  var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea($(selector).get(0), {
    mode: 'javascript',
    theme: 'paraiso-dark',
    lineNumbers : true
  });
  editor.setSize(320, 240);
  editor.getDoc().setValue(JSON.stringify(getSampleData(), null, 4));
  
  $('#response').text(allEqual([
    document.querySelector(selector).nextSibling,        // Native - Functional
    document.querySelector(selector + ' + .CodeMirror'), // Native - Selector
    $(selector).next('.CodeMirror').get(0),              // jQuery - Functional
    $(selector + ' + .CodeMirror').get(0)                // jQuery - Selector
  ]));
});

function allEqual(arr) {
  return arr.every(function(current, index, all) {
    return current === all[(index + 1) % all.length];
  });
};

// Return sample JSON data.
function getSampleData() {
 return [
        { color: "red",     value: "#f00" },
        { color: "green",   value: "#0f0" },
        { color: "blue",    value: "#00f" }
    ];
}
```

```css
#response { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.7.0/codemirror.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.7.0/theme/paraiso-dark.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.7.0/codemirror.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>All equal?: <span id="response"></span></div>
<textarea rows="10" cols="60" id="code"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using with `Vue CLI 3`, `vue-codemirror` component like this:

```
<codemirror id="textarea_editor" v-model="textarea_input" :options="cm_editor_config"></codemirror>
```

import `codemirror` to use within page:

```
import { codemirror } from 'vue-codemirror'
import 'codemirror/lib/codemirror.css'
```

and simply add `codemirror` inside `components` object, thereafter configuration in `data` section is:

```
codemirror_editor: undefined,
cm_editor_config: {
    tabSize: 4,
    mode: 'application/json',
    theme: 'base16-dark',
    lineNumbers: true,
    // lineWrapping: true,
    styleActiveSelected: true,
    line: true,
}
```

and initialized the object in `mounted` lifecycle section of `Vue`:

```
mounted () {
    if ( !this.codemirror_editor ) {
        this.codemirror_editor = $('#textarea_editor').find('.CodeMirror').get(0).CodeMirror;
    }
    // do something with this.codemirror_editor
}
```

Hope this would help many one.

Answer (score -2):

You can simply drop the **var**: instead of having

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea...
```

Just have

```
editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea...
```

Then **editor** is directly available to use in other functions

Comment: This is a bad idea, as dropping the `var` statement is equal to using `window.editor = ...` - it pollutes the global namespace and potentially overwrites existing variables.