# Using nightwatchjs to test a page with a CodeMirror component in it

Tags: javascript, selenium, automated-tests, codemirror, nightwatch.js

I am attempting to edit a query on a page in a web application that uses a  [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) component. I am using [nightwatchjs](http://nightwatchjs.org/) with selenium in chrome for the test. I can't set the underlying textarea element as it is not visible. Nightwatchjs `setValue` method doesn't work as the query is in an editable div.

Example Attempt:

```
module.exports = {

'Testing save code change' : function (browser) {

browser
  .url("http://codemirror.net/index.html")
  .waitForElementVisible("#demo", 3000)
  .waitForElementVisible('.CodeMirror-code div:nth-child(3) .cm-string', 3000)
  .setValue('.CodeMirror-code div:nth-child(3) .cm-string', 'New String');

 }

};
```

Can anyone suggest an approach that will work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could click the CodeMirror element and then use [keys()](http://nightwatchjs.org/api/keys.html) to do the typing.

```
browser.click('.CodeMirror textarea').keys('New String');
```

This will prepend the value to whatever is already inside the text area, so you'd have to do a bit more wrangling to delete whatever's there if you need to.

Alternatively, you could use nightwatch.js's [execute()](http://nightwatchjs.org/api/execute.html) function to call CodeMirror's `setValue()` directly, relying on the fact that you can [get the CodeMirror instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581516/get-codemirror-instance) directly from the DOM element.

```
browser.execute(function(text) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('CodeMirror')[0].CodeMirror.setValue(text);
}, ["you could also pass a variable in here"]);
```

Unlike the first option, it won't trigger all the same things as typing directly would (e.g. hints/autocompletions) but it'll correctly set an exact value.