# From @ctrl/ngx-codemirror library, how to get the codeMirror instance with typeScript and angular 5

Tags: typescript, angular5, codemirror

I am using the code-mirror wrapper from https://github.com/TypeCtrl/ngx-codemirror

I am trying to get the instance of Codemirror or the Editor to edit some actions but I am not able to get the instance.

related question: [Get CodeMirror instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581516/get-codemirror-instance)

I need to add a text in the current cursor position on click of a button, thus need the CodeMirror APIs.

Comment: what did you try already? Did you try using tplRef and ViewChild?

Comment: tried viewchild and document.getElementByClassName('CodeMirror')
in first case its a ElementRef which cant be assigned to Editor
in the second case its Element and this also cant be assigned to Editor instance

Comment: Hi @TanmoyBhattacharjee I have a similar problem, I have opened an issue in the ngx-codemirror repo FYI: https://github.com/TypeCtrl/ngx-codemirror/issues/109

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have solved this. Follow the below steps to get the instance:

```
import * as CodeMirror from 'codemirror';
```

Tag your code mirror instance in your html file:

```
    <ngx-codemirror #codeeditor
                [(ngModel)]="somemodel"
                [options]="someoptions"
                [autoFocus]=true
                (change)="callBackFunc()"
                (cursorActivity)="functionCall()">
</ngx-codemirror>
```

Read the instance with view-child

```
@ViewChild('codeeditor') private codeEditor;
```

Then you can get the editor object it in the relevant function:

```
const editor = this.codeEditor.codeMirror;
const doc = editor.getDoc();
```

Make sure you do not use it in the ngOnInit(), instead use it in ngAfterViewInit() with the setTimeOut() as the editor will be available for use only after the view loads fully.

Comment: Avoid using setTimeout() for deferring function execution as you don't know, how much time will loading take.

Answer (score 0):

I used the accepted answer for years but after updating to the latest version of `ngx-codeMirror`(`7.0.0`), the accepted answer stopped working for me. The `codeMirrorComponent.codeMirror` was still being reported as `undefined` in the `AfterViewInit` method.

Now though, there is a convenient eventEmitter for [codeMirrorLoaded](https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-codemirror?tab=readme-ov-file#outputs) that you can use to avoid any race conditions with the setup.

```
<ngx-codemirror ...
      (codeMirrorLoaded)="setCodeMirrorEvents($event)">
    </ngx-codemirror>
```

Then you can grab the instance like this

```
setCodeMirrorEvents(editor: CodemirrorComponent){
    const codeMirror = editor.codeMirror; //get editor from component

  }
```